# How to build a project and load the SDK with maven

Tags: java, maven, sdk

I have to create a pom.xml, which builds the entire project. But it won't load the SDK.

I tried to include dependencies, but it didn't work.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.swp18gi.zugumzugeuropa</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>ZugUmZug</name>
<description>Zug um Zug Europa</description>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <java.version>10</java.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <debug>false</debug>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>common</module>
    <module>server</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: This question is too broad, give an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Follow the [Maven in 5 minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) to quick start with Maven

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `But it won't load SKD`?

Answer (score 0):

It is given like the below :

`<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>`

Please reformat your pom.xml . Reference URL : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: also you need to have jdk 10 installed on your machine before you do this .

Answer (score 0):

Forking out the java compiler does not mean that Maven does any work in locating an appropriate JVM for you.

My guess is that you want Maven to use a JDK including the compiler instead of the standard JRE the `java` command installed by default under Windows belong to.

The correct way to do this is to tell Maven which JDK-JVM to use (or - for advanced users - to tell it to use the Eclipse compiler)

You can either do it by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to an appropriate JDK you have downloaded and installed (these days Oracle only wants paying users so the Zulu version of OpenJDK is a suitable alternative - https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/) or by providing the full path to the javac you want to use in the `<executable>` tag.  See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#executable for full details.